# Send POST request in application/x-protobuf and receive response in application/x-protobuf using soapUI

Tags: soapui, http-post, protocol-buffers

I'm new to SoapUI, my service requires application/x-protobuf as an input for request and output for response. I've been searching in the internet these days and found out that I need to serialize my object to pass it into the request. However, the POST request in SoapUI only accept string value. Can any body show me how to send the POST request with media type application/x-protobuf?

Regards,
Sam

Answer (score 0):

When you open the test step, in the upper left-hand corner there is a box that says 'Accept'. Try typing application/x-protobuf in there and send the POST request.